# AutoMapper.Mapper does not contain definition for CreateMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

This might be a basic question but wondering I am not getting AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap method.

[image]

Am I using wrong AutoMapper reference/package? Thanks

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The static version of the `CreateMap` method was deprecated in 4.2, then removed from the API in version 5.0. Jimmy Bogard talks about this in more detail in [this blog post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/).

The new technique for mapping is non-static, like this (code is from the post):

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = new Source();
var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source);
```

Comment: Thanks Will, wondering if you can advise how to use .ForMember() method, as couldn't find exact answer for my needs.

Comment: Thank I found the way as below: might be helpful for others

var configStack = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<StackInfoVM, StackNameVM>().ForMember(dest => dest.stackId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.itemId)) ; }
            );

Comment: I've same issue, i have tried as you suggested but gives me an error `The type or namespace name 'MapperConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and also same for `IMapper` Can you please help me.

Comment: Could I add all mapping config in one config for all of my model?

Comment: @MasterProgrammer Yup! I most commonly see the configuration created as a static property with all the mappings created inside of it.

Comment: CreateMap<DomainObject, Dto>();

Answer (score 50):

Here is how I used AutoMapper in my code.

Step 1 : Downloaded **AutoMapper** through **nuget-packages**.

Version is

```
<package id="AutoMapper" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Step 1 : Created **DTO** class

```
public class NotificationDTO
{

    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }
    public NotificationType Type { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? OriginalDateTime { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalVenue { get; private set; }
    public ConcertDTO Concert { get; set; }
}

public class ConcertDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelled { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }

}
```

Step 2 : Created an **AutoMapperProfile** class which inherits from **Profile**

```
using AutoMapper;
using ConcertHub.DTOs;

namespace ConcertHub.Models
{
  public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
  {
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Concert, ConcertDTO>();
        CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDTO>();
    }
  }
}
```

Step 3 : Registered **AutoMapperProfile** in the **Application Start** method of **Global.asax** file

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>());

    }
```

Finally the magic piece of code in the Api Controller

```
public IEnumerable<NotificationDTO> GetNewNotification()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var notifications = _dbContext.UserNotifications
                .Where(un => un.UserId == userId && !un.IsRead)
                .Select(un => un.Notification)
                .Include(n => n.Concert)
                .ProjectTo<NotificationDTO>()//use Automapper.QueryableExtension namespace
                .ToList();

        return notifications;
    }
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: Easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like Mosh's tutorial from Pluralsight :-)

Comment: @Casperonian you are right dear :-). Glad it helped others.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks.Better to explain in a good Practice way instead of just dumping the lines of code.

Comment: Just wondering if this is working for Auto Mapper Version after Version 5.0?. The issue I am facing is, its working for version 4.1.1. But the moment I change it to a version higher than 4.0, its saying Mapper dont have CreateMap.

Comment: There's no `Mapper.Initialize` method anymore.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how it works now:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SupervisorEmployee, SupervisorViewModel>()
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Name, src => src.MapFrom<string>(e => SupervisorViewModel.MapName(e)))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.OfficePhone, src => src.MapFrom<string>(e => e.OfficePhone.FormatPhone(e.OfficePhoneIsForeign)))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.HomePhone, src => src.MapFrom<string>(e => e.HomePhone.FormatPhone(e.HomePhoneIsForeign)))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.MobilePhone, src => src.MapFrom<string>(e => e.MobilePhone.FormatPhone(e.MobilePhoneIsForeign)));
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I see your class didn't inherit from AutoMapper.Profile

I did this and worked for me

```
public class AutoMapperConfig: AutoMapper.Profile
```

Comment: Why is this not the to answer?

Comment: no idea... guess not that many people make this mistake