# Automapper: Mapping an object to a LIST

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have a type`SupportedCurrencies` that contains a list of objects of type `Currency`:

```
  public class SupportedCurrencies
        {
            public List<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
        }
  public class Currency
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }    
        public string AmountMin { get; set; }
        public string AmountMax { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to map it to a list of objects of type `SupportedCurrency`:

```
    public class SupportedCurrency
    {
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public string MinAmount { get; set; }
        public string MaxAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

In my mapping profile I have the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<Response.Currency, SupportedCurrency>()
            .ForMember(p => p.MinAmount, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.AmountMin))
            .ForMember(p => p.MaxAmount, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.AmountMax))
            .ForMember(p => p.CurrencyCode, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.Code));

CreateMap<SupportedCurrencies, IList<SupportedCurrency>>().ConvertUsing(MappingFunction);
```

And the converter looks like this:

```
 private IList<SupportedCurrency> MappingFunction(SupportedCurrencies arg1, IList<SupportedCurrency> arg2, ResolutionContext arg3)
        {
            foreach (var item in arg1.Currencies)
            {
                arg2.Add(arg3.Mapper.Map<SupportedCurrency>(item)); 
            }
            return arg2;
        }
```

But when I try to map it:

```
_mapper.Map<IList<SupportedCurrency>>(obj01.SupportedCurrencies);
```

I get back an exception saying:

```
Method 'get_Item' in type 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.IList`1 is not implemented.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static version of `CreateMap` is removed: [AutoMapper.Mapper does not contain definition for CreateMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194012/automapper-mapper-does-not-contain-definition-for-createmap)

I do not know whether you have choice of upgrading. But with latest `AutoMapper` (10.1.1), following code works (you did not give the completed code so I created object of `SupportedCurrencies`)

```
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Currency, SupportedCurrency>()
                    .ForMember(p => p.MinAmount, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.AmountMin))
                    .ForMember(p => p.MaxAmount, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.AmountMax))
                    .ForMember(p => p.CurrencyCode, q => q.MapFrom(r => r.Code));

            });


            SupportedCurrencies supportedCurrencies = new SupportedCurrencies();
            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            mapper.Map<IList<SupportedCurrency>>(supportedCurrencies);
```