# The disappearing, reappearing Moq reference

Tags: moq

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961775/mysterious-disappearing-reference) describes the problem I'm having, but I'm not aware of any dependencies that Moq might have. Has anyone experienced this, or is anyone aware of Moq dependencies? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you're targeting the .Net Client Profile and not the full framework.

In Visual Studio, right click on your project and choose properties.  Make sure your target framework is `.NET 4 Framework` and not `.NET 4 Framework Client Profile`.

It should look like this:

[image]